# I can t install the Asus USB-AC68 Wireless-AC1900 USB WI-FI adater in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: kernel, compiling

I use Ubuntu 17.10 artful 4.13.0-16-generic.

But I can't install the Asus USB-AC68, I tried to install the rtl8814AU driver.

I tried a lot commandos from your site, the last one is:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git dkms 
git clone https://github.com/sbosshardt/rtl8814AU.git cd rtl8814AU sudo
./dkms-install.sh
```

I get this error in the console:

```
/rtl8814AU# sudo ./dkms-install.sh About to run dkms install steps...

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/source ->
                 /usr/src/rtl8814AU-4.3.21

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module: cleaning build area... 'make'...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8814AU: 4.3.21 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.13.0-16-generic
(x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/make.log for
more information.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module: cleaning build area... 'make'...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8814AU: 4.3.21 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.13.0-16-generic
(x86_64) Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/make.log for
more information. Finished running dkms install steps.
```

This is the `/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/make.log`

```
DKMS make.log for rtl8814AU-4.3.21 for kernel 4.13.0-16-generic
(x86_64) di 24 okt 2017 12:18:51 CEST make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE=
-C /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build  modules make[1]: Map
'/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-16-generic' wordt binnengegaan   CC [M]
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/core/rtw_cmd.o In file included
from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/include/drv_types.h:32:0,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/core/rtw_cmd.c:22:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/include/osdep_service.h: In
function ‘thread_enter’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/include/osdep_service.h:343:2:
error: implicit declaration of function ‘allow_signal’; did you mean
‘do_signal’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]  
allow_signal(SIGTERM);   ^~~~~~~~~~~~   do_signal
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/include/osdep_service.h: In
function ‘flush_signals_thread’:
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/include/osdep_service.h:353:6:
error: implicit declaration of function ‘signal_pending’; did you mean
‘timer_pending’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]   if
(signal_pending (current))
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      timer_pending /var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/include/osdep_service.h:355:3:
error: implicit declaration of function ‘flush_signals’; did you mean
‘do_signal’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]   
flush_signals(current);    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~    do_signal cc1: some
warnings being treated as errors scripts/Makefile.build:302: recept
voor doel '/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/core/rtw_cmd.o' is
mislukt make[2]: ***
[/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build/core/rtw_cmd.o] Fout 1
Makefile:1546: recept voor doel
'_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build' is mislukt make[1]: ***
[_module_/var/lib/dkms/rtl8814AU/4.3.21/build] Fout 2 make[1]: Map
'/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-16-generic' wordt verlaten
Makefile:1699: recept voor doel 'modules' is mislukt make: ***
[modules] Fout 2
```

Please this Kubie needs some help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this repo:
https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au.git

no easy install scripts, but just
        sudo make && sudo make install

Comment: sudo is not needed for building, only for install