# installing rtl8814AU wifi adapter driver on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, software-installation, realtek-wireless

I'm trying to install an `rtl18814` driver  for an ASUS USB AC68 wifi adapter.  There have been quite a few threads about this, which being ignorant I found impenetrable.   But there was one thread that seemed straightforward.    Following the suggestion by @SomeOne01 from [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968506/i-can-t-install-the-asus-usb-ac68-wireless-ac1900-usb-wi-fi-adater-in-ubuntu-17), I downloaded a zipfile called `rtl8814au-master.zip`from [this site](https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au.git) and followed @SomeOne01's instructions.    It worked seamlessly on Ubuntu 18.04, which was a first in my ubuntu experience.     But unfortunately I needed the adapter on a machine running 16.04 (xenial).     When I ran `make` on that machine, I got the following error.

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-139-generic/build M=/usr/local/src/rtl8814au-master  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-139-generic'
  CC [M]  /usr/local/src/rtl8814au-master/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o
/usr/local/src/rtl8814au-master/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c: In function  rtw_get_systime_us :
/usr/local/src/rtl8814au-master/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c:352:2: error: implicit declaration of function  ktime_get_boottime_ts64’[-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  ktime_get_boottime_ts64(&ts);
  ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:277: recipe for target '/usr/local/src/rtl8814au-master/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/usr/local/src/rtl8814au-master/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o] Error 1
Makefile:1439: recipe for target '_module_/usr/local/src/rtl8814au-master' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/usr/local/src/rtl8814au-master] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-139-generic'
Makefile:1699: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Could anybody please suggest  how to proceed on 16.04 xenial?

Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Comment: What kernel are you running on your 16.04 LTS?  The download says it's for 4.15 or later so do you have HWE enabled?  (default kernel for 16.04 LTS is 4.4, but with HWE enabled 16.04 uses 4.15, and the instructions tell you 4.14 is required at a minimum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be easier if you do

```
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au.git
cd rtl8814au
git checkout 7dde5bd
```

Then see if `make` succeeds.  If the `make` command has no errors I would do

```
make clean
cd ..
sudo apt install dkms
sudo dkms add ./rtl8814au
sudo dkms install rtl8814au/4.3.21
```

Reboot

There is an issue with the latest commit https://github.com/zebulon2/rtl8814au/commit/3cf715db6f8e021671b72918929a307847e77e92 as the kernel version specified for it should have been 4.17

If you happen to have no internet connection, edit the file usr/local/src/rtl8814au-master/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c at line 350 you will find

```
#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,39))
```

Change it to

```
#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(4,17,0))
```

Then the make command should work without errors

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy31, I just did the edit you suggested to the .c file and it worked like a charm.

Comment: What can I do for Ubuntu with kernel 5.4.0-45-generic and the newer ac1900 ac68 wifi adapter from asus?

Comment: Github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au works with rtl8814au

Comment: @Jeremy31, it worked three months ago on Ubuntu 18.04 but now I'm on 20.04 and it seems like the instructions have changed at that repo.  Please look at my new question when you have a moment:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1302624/rtl8812au-21au-wireless-drivers-vs-rtl8814au-for-asus-ac68-ac1900-wireless-ada